# Unable to print multiple columns

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to print out multiple columns using the command below but it's not working.
Can somebody please check what am I missing.

```
grep -i "$(echo ${vdisk}| awk '{print $1,$2}' 2>/dev/null)" ${GBL_TEMP}/vdisk_*
```

using the above command, it will print everything and will not parse the $1 and $2

so I tried this

```
grep -i "$(echo ${vdisk}| awk '{print $1,$2,$4,$5,$7,$8,$10}' 2>/dev/null)" ${GBL_TEMP}/vdisk_*
```

but still no luck.

I'm trying to print these columns `{print $1,$2,$4,$5,$7,$8,$10}`

output of $vdisk

```
745 ptr3p_002       0           io_grp0       online 16           B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 11.00GB  striped               745   ptr3p_002       60050768019181B398000000000004DF 0            1          not_empty        0             no        0                     16                  B1_DID_T1N_ABG1       no         no      745       ptr3p_002       master
```

Comment: post the output of `echo ${vdisk}`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, added it on my post.

Comment: I think you shouldn't add columns to your awk, which changes the matching criteria, but rather pipe the output of `grep` (a full line), into an another `awk` (or `cut`) that would extract the columns you want. Currently I guess your command doesn't output anything because the files don't contain lines where the 1st, 2nd, 4th,5th,7th,8th and 10th columns of your variable are found adjacent (which is the output of your awk -> the matching criteria of grep)

Comment: @Aaron, i tried using grep then `>` to a file. However, $vdisk contains multiple string to be searched in `${GBL_TEMP}/vdisk_*`. Unfortunately, i don't know why, only 1 output is being redirected.

Comment: your `awk` command outputs `745 ptr3p_002 io_grp0 online B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 11.00GB 745`. Is that string what you want to search for in the `${GBL_TEMP}/vdisk_*` files?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here. Please provide your actual input (sample of vdisk files) and your exact desired output. Stack Overflow has a guided question mode which will help you get better feedback by providing information in an organized way.

Comment: Thank you guys for being patient. So i was able to make a workaround, the only missing piece is the $vdisk which i searched. `grep ${vdisk} ${TEMP}/vdisk_* | awk -F, '{print $1,$2,$4,$5,$7,$8,$10}' | awk -F '/export/home/GBL/SVC/temp/vdisk_' '{print $NF}' 2> /dev/null` . `${vdisk} = $10`. How can i also make it appear? All these $1,$2,$4,$5,$7,$8 are printed except $10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unsure in which column the 32 character string will be located, you could use the following to test the length of the string for each variable. Only if it is always 32 characters:

3 Variants of file vdisk:

File vdisk1 has 32 Character string as **$10**

```
745 ptr3p_002 0 io_grp0 online 16 B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 11.00GB striped 745 1 60050768019181B398000000000004DF 0 1 not_empty 0 no 0 16 B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 no no 745 ptr3p_002 master
```

File vdisk2 has 32 Character string as **$11**

```
745 ptr3p_002 0 io_grp0 online 16 B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 11.00GB striped 1 1 60050768019181B398000000000004DF 0 1 not_empty 0 no 0 16 B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 no no 745 ptr3p_002 master
```

File vdisk3 has 32 Character string  **$12**

```
745 ptr3p_002 0 io_grp0 online 16 B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 11.00GB striped 745 ptr3p_002 60050768019181B398000000000004DF 0 1 not_empty 0 no 0 16 B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 no no 745 ptr3p_002 master
```

It's crude but it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
for each in vdisk*
do
    var10=$(awk '{print $10}' $each)
    var11=$(awk '{print $11}' $each)
    var12=$(awk '{print $12}' $each)

for i in $var10 $var11 $var12
    do
    check=${#i}
    if [ $check -eq 32 ]; then
    char32=$i
    fi
done

awkout=$(awk '{print $1, $2, $4, $5, $7, $8}' $each)

echo  "$awkout $char32" | xargs

done
```

Output on all files:

```
745 ptr3p_002 io_grp0 online B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 11.00GB 60050768019181B398000000000004DF
745 ptr3p_002 io_grp0 online B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 11.00GB 60050768019181B398000000000004DF
745 ptr3p_002 io_grp0 online B1_DID_T1N_ABG1 11.00GB 60050768019181B398000000000004DF
```

Comment: `$vdisk` is also column `$10` which consist of this 32 digits --> `60050768019181B398000000000004DF`.. i don't know why even if i tried to do this command `awk -F, '{print $1, $2, $4, $5, $7, $8; $10}' vdisk_*`, only that column is not printing out. :(

Comment: There are no commas in your vdisk example so that cannot be the -F which is the input field separator

Comment: opps.. sorry added that in purpose for the new vdisk result. Anyhow even if I remove it, this 32 digit is not printing out. This is, by the way, a LUN ID from the storage. Not sure if you're familiar with that. Don't know if this is considered as ascii, but if it is, do you know how can i print it out as is?

Comment: Using your example vdisk, the 32 character string is $12.

Comment: Ok, i think i know where the problem is. That 32 character string is not just in column $10. It's location changes. It could either be in column $10, $11 or $12. Now, the question is. How can i include those strings given that scenario?

Comment: I've updated the information. Check and see if it suits.

Comment: Thank you @Alfred E. Noobman. Your script helped me a lot.  Cheers! :)